# Printing HTML in iOS

Tags: ios, printing, margin

I'm using following code for printing at the moment. Note that i have the requirement of HTML printing.

```
UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
printInfo.jobName = @"Sample";
pic.printInfo = printInfo;

NSString *htmlString = [self prepareHTMLEmailMessage];
UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter *htmlFormatter = [[UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter alloc] initWithMarkupText:htmlString];
htmlFormatter.startPage = 0;
htmlFormatter.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0); // 1-inch margins on all sides
htmlFormatter.maximumContentWidth = 6 * 72.0;   // printed content should be 6-inches wide within those margins
pic.printFormatter = htmlFormatter;
[htmlFormatter release];

pic.showsPageRange = YES;

void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {

    if (!completed && error) {
        NSLog(@"Printing could not complete because of error: %@", error);
    }
};

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    [pic presentFromBarButtonItem:self.myPrintBarButton animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

} else {
    [pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

The result produced doesn't give me consistent margins on all pages. Part of the problem is the `contentInsets` property. As per Apple's documentation: The top inset applies only to the first page of printed content. 
[image: Sample Output generated by the code above]

I want the output to have consistent margins, just like the output produced by Safari.[image: Print output produced by Safari]

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `UIPrintPageRenderer` subclass with `UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter` solved my problem. Apple's sample code helped.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you've already got your working answer, but a `UIPrintPageRenderer` *subclass* is not strictly necessary if all you are doing is adding a blank header and footer to pad out each printed page - just instantiate a vanilla `UIPrintPageRenderer` and set the `headerHeight` and `footerHeight` properties, then add your `UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter` to the renderer.

I posted my method on your other question: [Print paper size and content inset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817840/print-paper-size-and-content-inset/5988357#5988357)